# How to check whether the image is stored in database or not from JAVA/JSP?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc

I have column to save image. I have use "BLOB" type  in database to store image. Now, I want to check whether the user submitted picture or not from JSP page. How can I achieve this?

The previous version of this question is in 
[How to compare whether the BLOB of database (mysql) is empty or not in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922160/how-to-compare-whether-the-blob-of-database-mysql-is-empty-or-not-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is as such no way to check. You can either make it a not null column which will ensure the image is always saved or you can give the control to the user to edit/delete the saved image which will also ensure the image is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Very open question. You can do this at multiple layers:

1) Check in your servlets assuming you are using pure jsp/servlets and not a framework like struts, spring mvc. 
2) Only save into DB, if image is uploaded. 
3) Make this column a not null column?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if a column in DB is populated from your servlet/jsp or not. Maybe you can add a extra column which gets populated when you are saving image from jsp/servlet. That way you can verify.